# Scope a model on an assocation attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, named-scope

I have a User model (used for authentication/authorization) with an associated Profile model (used for information about the user, ie haircolor).

I am trying to create a scope to find all of the users with a particular attribute. ie: all dark haired people (hair color is black or brown), or all light haired people (hair color is blond or silver).

I can find all profiles with dark hair, but how do I find the associated users.

app/models/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
```

app/models/profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  scope :dark_hair, -> { where('hair_color = ? or hair_color = ?', 'black', 'brown' }
  scope :light_hair, -> { where('hair_color = ? or hair_color = ?', 'blond', 'silver' }
```

So I can find the profiles:

```
irb>> Profile.dark_hair
```

But I can't get the users (none of these work):

```
irb>> Profile.dark_hair.user
irb>> Profile.dark_hair.users
irb>> User.profile.dark_hair
```

How do I ask for the users I want?  Or should the scope be on the User?  I tried that but couldn't figure out how to write it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `merge`:

```
User.joins(:profile).merge(Profile.dark_hair)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge

Comment: Thanks this worked! Even on the original, non-simplified version.